# Does heat sink of laptop contain any coolant?

Tags: heatsink

Heat sink of a laptop consists of copper tube. It is used to cool the processor and other electronics. Does the tube contain any coolant or it is just air filled?

Comment: The tube is called a ["heat pipe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pipe)

Comment: Related: [CPU cooler does not fit, will it cool worse if I cut tips of heatpipes off?](http://superuser.com/questions/1174128/cpu-cooler-does-not-fit-will-it-cool-worse-if-i-cut-tips-of-heatpipes-off), and [What's the point of heat pipes?](http://superuser.com/questions/970624/whats-the-point-of-heat-pipes?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a heat pipe. Heat pipes do contain coolant, which evaporates easily (thus cooling the bottom where it evaporates) and the fluid condenses again after shedding its heat elsewhere.

Its main purpose is to transfer heat away from the source to the heat sink.

Comment: There's a good explanation [here](https://www.aavid.com/product-group/heatpipe/operate).